# how to make my apache website accept only host header with a specific entry

Tags: php, apache, request-headers

my website is under attack and I see that the attacker is bypassing the cloudflare security by entering the website with the IP and not with domain name, I am wandering if I can protect my website by making my apache-based website block all the requests that doesn't have the name of my website in the host header of the attackers requests

Comment: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/prevent-direct-access-to-ip/89575

Comment: May be a better way but https://serverfault.com/questions/583884/apache-listen-only-on-specific-domain-not-ip

Comment: @ADyson unfortunately both links in the accepted answer on that thread are dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you *did* do this all the attacker has to do is add the header to their requests and you're still having the same problem. You need to block access from non-cloudflare IP ranges at the firewall.

https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

Make sure that you put in an allow your for yourself for testing.

Answer (score -2):

i don't know if this will protect my website "and" i forgot to mention that i am using xampp windows

anyway from the xampp rules file i just entered

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'website'">
</If>
<Else>
  RewriteRule ^.*$ http://website/$1 [L]
</Else>
```

and it worked

that's it that's the answer for the question i asked

Comment: You have not actually fixed the backdoor problem, you've put up a sign that says "please go in the front" which will only work until whoever is DOSing you realizes that they just have to set the correct header and then you're back to square one. Put a lock on the door, block non-Cloudflare access.